# Handling request in django inclusion template tag

Tags: django, templates, request, templatetags

I am new to Django and am trying to put an upload file form into an inclusion tag. So I can use it in various templates.

I have created the following inclusion tag:

```
#upload_files.py

@register.inclusion_tag('upload_form.html')
def upload_handler(context):
    request = context['request']
    view_url = reverse('upload.views.upload_handler')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(view_url)

    upload_url, upload_data = prepare_upload(request, view_url)
    form = UploadForm()

    upload_model_list = UploadModel.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
```

I wish to now include this in a template, so on the page I have:

```
#mypage.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load upload_files %}

{% upload_handler %}
```

I get the following error:

```
upload_handler takes 1 arguments
```

What argument should I be passing from the template?

Answer (score 13):

You need to add `takes_context=True` when registering the tag to get django pass the context object to the function:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('upload_form.html', takes_context=True)
```

Per default `context` will always be the first argument then!

For further details see django's documentation on [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

A side note: Decide carefully on what pages you use this template tag on, because a view may render additional forms/handle post requests in a certain way that might collide with the logic your tag provides (eg. the form validation will be triggered if the page may be called by a post request coming from another form). You could eg. additionally check if some HTML element's name is in `request.POST` if you have multiple forms on a page!

Comment: I am having that problem!! I use a template tag everywhere on my webpage cause it contains the login form. After login, I try to pass a parameter to modify something in the template tag, (via request.POST) but when the login templatetag reload again, request.method = GET!!! so I cannot find tha parameter. How can I find that parameter?

Comment: Well the method will be `GET` again because the login view most probably does a redirect after the form was sent, so you can't access your request data there...